# Hand luggage weight?

Tags: luggage

The normal allowance for hand luggage with easyjet is 8-12kgs.There is mention of 10kg on my reservation details. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Hmm, yes. Why the confusion?

Comment: 10kg is generous when it comes to hand luggage, I remember having seen 8kg.

Answer (score 3):

actually if you have a look at the easyjet [website](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/baggage/cabin-bag-and-hold-luggage) you can see that there are no limits on the hand luggage weight, but just on the size:

> There’s no weight limit but we do ask that you are able to lift it into the overhead locker.

maybe you should double check your reservation details inside your personal area in the easyjet website.

Comment: My question or issue is not about  weight. What I want to know is there is mention of 10kg on the reservation details where easy jet website (as VAL's comment) clearly states no weight limit on hand luggage? The normal allowance for hand luggage with easyjet is 8-12kgs anyway.

Comment: @Dray The EasyJet webpage says 8-12kg, and your EasyJet reservation says 10kg. Sometimes things change; sometimes people screw up. If the check-in clerks care, it'd be a lot easier for them to point to *your reservation* for the terms *of your ticket.* I'd be prepared for a 10kg limit.